# как вывести данные mysql для конкретного пользователя PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Мне нужно вывести данные , которые введет пользователь через форму в Mysql именно на его столбец и вывести все данные , которые он вел , ему на страницу.

Вывод получается , только отображается и другим пользователям.

У меня есть две таблицы:

1. Таблица - **users** , где хранится информация пользователей - имя , пароль , аватарка.
2. Таблица - **POSTtable** , где сохраняются посты пользователей.

Структура таблицы **users** - **id , fname , username , password**

Структура таблицы **POSTtable** - **id , text , content , image_path**.

**Файл postzapros.php**

```
 <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "root" , "", "root");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM POSTtable";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $text = $_REQUEST['text'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO POSTtable(text  VALUES ('$text')";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}

?>
```

**Файл home.php**

```
**Форма php**
    <form action="home.php" method="GET" class="formpost" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <div class="inputform">
                    <textarea  name="text"  maxlength="305" placeholder="       Добавить запись"></textarea>
                <div class="divs">
                <input type="file"  class="inputs" name="files"  multiple />    
                <i class="fa fa-image fa-2x icons" style="font-size: 1.70em; margin-left: 15em; margin-top: 47px;"></i> 
                <button type="submit" name="submit" >></button>
                
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: вы попробуйте какую-нибудь самую простенькую кникжу по базам данных прочитать сначала. Там раскажут,к ак таблицы можно вместе связывать.

Comment: Так в таблице `POSTtable` нет никакого указания на принадлежность поста кому-либо. Добавь столбец, например, `autor` и уже по нему будешь отбирать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM POSTtable WHERE id = "нужное значание"